# What does save_base with the argument raw=True do in Django?

Tags: django

New to Django and programming and can't seem to find any official documentation for save_base with the argument raw=True.  Can someone please spell it out to me what it does?  Haven't been able to find any google results that give a thorough explanation.

Comment: The public API is `Model.save()`. You should never have to call `save_base()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be [undocumented](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/) in the latest Django release indeed.
Have a [look at the comments in the source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/405ec5b9c6996bf4e5fba68a9bad76d17e146327/django/db/models/base.py#L735) to find out what it does:

> The 'raw' argument is telling save_base not to save any parent models
> and not to do any changes to the values before save. This is used by
> fixture loading.

Comment: Thankyou For This!!

Comment: Thanks @Saex ! That link to source might change (the line numbers are already diffreent. Here is [a permalink](https://github.com/django/django/blob/405ec5b9c6996bf4e5fba68a9bad76d17e146327/django/db/models/base.py#L735).